# How to handle consuming from a Kafka topic that is reset every day

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm consuming from a third-party Kafka topic, so I don't have any control over the producer side of things. Every day, the topic is cleared and reset.

If I'm committing offsets, and I want to be, this causes problems. I see these error logs:

```
%4|1705281234.978|OFFSET|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: topic_name [11]:
offset reset (at offset 178300963 (leader epoch -1), broker 6) to offset BEGINNING (leader epoch -1):
fetch failed due to requested offset not available on the broker:
Broker: Offset out of range
```

Ideally, this would throw an error which I could then catch, and then force a reset of the offset. However, I don't think this is how Kafka is designed, if I'm reading [the `librdkafka` source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aconfluentinc%2Flibrdkafka%20rd_kafka_offset_reset&type=code) right (note, I have not worked in C). I'm using the .NET client and I don't see anything there that would facilitate me doing this.

How would you handle this situation? All ideas are welcomed.

Comment: What does it mean 'topic is cleared and reset'?

Comment: @PawełSzymczyk, what the service provider has told me is that they "clear out the queue [topic] overnight". In other words, the history is removed, and if you replay the events from the beginning, it's only from the beginning of that day.